# How do I permanently merge two influxdb series data into one series?

Tags: time-series, influxdb

I have to work on an InfluxDB v1.8 instance that seems to hold too many series (at leasts after a quick peek at a `SHOW SERIES` result, but I'm still investigating).

Given that two different series really should be one - I guess they ended up like this because the wrong tag keys have been defined - do I have any chance to merge / unify their values in the database, I mean not when querying?

Probably some tags should be converted to fields, and of course I should not loose any time point; plus, the database is part of an architecture that loads data qith Telegraph - that should probably go in a separate question, but it is worth mentioning.